# For keywords(strings) in one column and values(floats) in another, I want to count the number ok keywords that fall per unit range of the value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
            keyword     val
    0   nt              0.93
    1   atm             0.94
    2   bank            1.00
    3   long            1.02
    4   number          1.11
    5   get             2.20
    6   money           3.50
    7   account         3.80
    8   deposit         3.90
    9   card            5.00
    10  credit          0.8
    11  debit           1.23
```

I want to find out the number of keywords per unit range of value
ie from 0.9-1 => [nt,atm]=>2
   from 1-1.1 => [bank,long,number] =>3 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `groupby` with some column value modifications, then use `count` on `'keyword'` column:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['val'].astype(int))['keyword'].count()
val
0    3
1    4
2    1
3    3
4    1
Name: keyword, dtype: int64
```

**Edit:**

```
>>> df.groupby(df['val'].apply("{:.1f}".format))['keyword'].count()
val
0.8    1
0.9    2
1.0    2
1.1    1
1.2    1
2.2    1
3.5    1
3.8    1
3.9    1
5.0    1
Name: keyword, dtype: int64
```

If mind rounding (`1.9` won't be in the same group as `1.1` though):

```
>>> df.groupby(df['val'].round(1))['keyword'].count()
val
0.8    1
0.9    2
1.0    2
1.1    1
1.2    1
2.2    1
3.5    1
3.8    1
3.9    1
5.0    1
Name: keyword, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I edited the question, I need it for every 0.1 interval

Comment: @Rasika See now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) here with `groupby()`:

```
bins=[0,1,2,3,5]

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.val,bins)).keyword.apply(list)
```

---

```
val
(0, 1]                    [nt, atm, bank]
(1, 2]                     [long, number]
(2, 3]                              [get]
(3, 5]    [money, account, deposit, card]
```

For count use:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.val,bins)).keyword.size()
```

---

```
val
(0, 1]    3
(1, 2]    2
(2, 3]    1
(3, 5]    4
```

You can customize your bins like:

```
bins=[0,0.99,1,1.99,2,2.99,3,3.99,4,4.99,5]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.val,bins)).keyword.size()
```

---

```
val
(0.0, 0.99]    2
(0.99, 1.0]    1
(1.0, 1.99]    2
(1.99, 2.0]    0
(2.0, 2.99]    1
(2.99, 3.0]    0
(3.0, 3.99]    3
(3.99, 4.0]    0
(4.0, 4.99]    0
(4.99, 5.0]    1
```